# Use makeidx with hyperref in beamer

Tags: beamer, hyperref, makeidx

I am making kind of lecture notes for online lectures using the `beamer` class (in the presentation mode).

I need to use index. Using the advice from [Is it bug or feature? I cannot use makeidx in beamer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6793/is-it-bug-or-feature-i-cannot-use-makeidx-in-beamer), I managed how to use `makeidx` in `beamer` for my needs.

However, the page numbers in the index are not links (not clickable).

I know that the 'standard' way is to load `makeidx` before `hyperref`, but `beamer` loads `hyperref` by itself. I know about `\PassOptionsToPackage` and `\PassOptionsToClass`, but is it possible to 'pass' package (`makeidx`) to class (`beamer`) to be load 'first' (whatever this means...)?

**UPDATE** MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex
\newenvironment{theindex}
 {\let\item\par%
  \let\subitem\par%
  }{}
\newcommand\indexspace{}
\begin{document}
\index{A}{Index entry example A}
\begin{equation}
    1+1=2 \label{eq}
\end{equation}

\newpage

\index{B}{Index entry example B}

Equation \eqref{eq} reference is clickable (try!).

\newpage

\printindex
\end{document}
```

Comment: As always on the site you are much more likely to get help if you provide self contained minimal code others can copy and test.

Comment: Thank you. Done.

Comment: The problem is not only the loading order, but beamer also loads hyperref with `\RequirePackage[implicit=false]{hyperref}`